# Scraping text from file within HTML tags

Tags: excel, web-scraping, extract, analysis, text-extraction

I have a file that I want to extract dates from, it's a HTML source file so it's full of code and phrases I don't need. I need to extract every instance of a date that's wrapped in a specific HTML tag:

abbr title="((this is the text I need))" data-utime="

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: This is *not* data-mining. Retitled and retagged to [tag:web-scraping].
Data mining is essentially a type of large scale *statistical analysis*; this is at most preprocessing for data mining. Oh, and why is this tagged "excel"?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Excel VBA, set a reference (Tools - References) to the MSHTML library (entitled `Microsoft HTML Object Library` in the reference menu)

```
Sub ScrapeDateAbbr()

    Dim hDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim hElem As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement
    Dim sFile As String, lFile As Long
    Dim sHtml As String

    'read in the file
    lFile = FreeFile
    sFile = "C:/Users/dick/Documents/My Dropbox/Excel/Testabbr.html"
    Open sFile For Input As lFile
    sHtml = Input$(LOF(lFile), lFile)

    'put into an htmldocument object
    Set hDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    hDoc.body.innerHTML = sHtml

    'loop through abbr tags
    For Each hElem In hDoc.getElementsByTagName("abbr")
        'only those that have a data-utime attribute
        If Len(hElem.getAttribute("data-utime")) > 0 Then
            'get the title attribute
            Debug.Print hElem.getAttribute("title")
        End If
    Next hElem

End Sub
```

I assumed the file was local since you called in a source file.  If you need to download it first, you'd need another reference to MSXML and this code

```
Sub ScrapeDateAbbrDownload()

    Dim xHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim hDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim hElem As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement

    Set xHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    xHttp.Open "GET", "file:///C:/Users/dick/Documents/My%20Dropbox/Excel/Testabbr.html"
    xHttp.send

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until xHttp.readyState = 4

    'put into an htmldocument object
    Set hDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    hDoc.body.innerHTML = xHttp.responseText

    'loop through abbr tags
    For Each hElem In hDoc.getElementsByTagName("abbr")
        'only those that have a data-utime attribute
        If Len(hElem.getAttribute("data-utime")) > 0 Then
            'get the title attribute
            Debug.Print hElem.getAttribute("title")
        End If
    Next hElem

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Java you could use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). This is unclear from your question, please elaborate on what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: So basically I have a 15mb file which is an extract from a saved web page. The page contains facebook messages and each message is date stamped, I want to do an analysis on messages per date so I need to extract every time a date appears. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: If the programming language doesn't matter then i'd certainly recommend JSoup

Comment: Or BeautifulSoup if you prefer python.