# Search a web page for a particular text

Tags: excel

I wanted to do something fancy to ease my browsing of a praticular site, but problem is I dont really know how to do it, or if it is even possible with excel.

What I want to do, is for excel to search a given page for a text like "Overstock". If it finds the word, it returns the result of "Full" or "Overstock" or the opposite in a given cell.

Reason for this is to check 100+ pages at once by just opening an excel, and giving separate result for each page.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758107

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want with a few modifications.

I have code in there to log into the website I use but might not be required for you.

I have chopped this up from a larger macro so there might be some bits that are not required in here.

```
Sub scraper()

        Dim site As String
        Dim lastRow As Long
        Dim ie

        With ActiveSheet
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        End With

            Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
            ie.Visible = True

            ie.navigate site

            'idle while ie is busy
            Do
            Loop Until ie.readystate = 3
            Do
            Loop Until ie.readystate = 4

            With ie.document
                .getelementbyid("UserName").Value = uName
                .getelementbyid("Password").Value = uPass
                .forms(0).submit
            End With
            On Error GoTo error

            Do
            Loop Until ie.readystate = 3
            Do
            Loop Until ie.readystate = 4

            For i = 2 To lastRow

                site = Range("A" & i).Value
                ie.navigate site

            Do
            Loop Until ie.readystate = 3
            Do
            Loop Until ie.readystate = 4


        msg = ie.document.Body.innerhtml
        If InStr(msg, "Text To Find") = 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value = "Not Found"
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value = "Found"
       End If
jump:
            Next i
        Exit Sub
error:
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value = "Unknown Error!"
Resume jump


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.