# vba excel - error 249 activex component can't create object

Tags: excel, activex, regsvr32, vba

I'm trying to create an HTML object in excel VBA but I get this error:

> `error 249 activex component can't create object`

The script works good in another computer but in my computer I always get this error. I heard about something called `regsvr32` but I didn't understand what should I do with this.

Which dll file/files should I register?

Comment: Being able to see the script would help in figuring this out.

Comment: this is the same script as here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100608/vba-copy-html-table-data-to-excel-worksheet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Excel ActiveX Controls Disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411399/microsoft-excel-activex-controls-disabled)